# Extract a string inside a line without whitespaces beetween other strings

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I have a txt like this:

```
[Server]
Version=3
DTBNumber=1
[DTB001]
DTBName=ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Native Client;UID=MAN;PWD=bingo156;DATABASE=SHITMAN;SERVER=(local);
DTBType=5
DTBnUtenti=1
DTBUtenti=002LUCA;
```

How can i extract the word "SHITMAN" between "DATABASE=" and ";" and store it in a variable with a batch?

Comment: Extracting information from a Windows INI file is a related more general problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following pure batch solution should work for most scenarios. But there are values that can cause it to crash, or give the wrong answer:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "ln="
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('findstr /r "DATABASE=.*;" "test.txt"') do set "ln=%%A"
if not defined ln (
  echo Value not found
  exit /b 1
)
for /f "delims=;=" %%A in ("%ln:*DATABASE=%") do set "val=%%A"
echo Value=%VAL%
```

There are ways to make pure batch more robust. But there is a simple tool that provides a very robust and easy to use solution: [REPL.BAT is a hybrid batch/JScript utility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735079/1012053) that performs regex search and replace on stdin and writes the result to stdout. The `A` option returns only lines that have been altered.

```
@echo off
set "val="
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('type test.txt^|repl ".*DATABASE=(.*?);.*" $1 a') do set "val=%%A"
echo Value=%VAL%
```

Poison characters could cause the last solution to fail when the value is printed to the screen. Use of delayed expansion in the last ECHO statement would make it work with any legal batch environment variable value.